# How to fix ambiguity error when working with overloaded operators in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm doing an assignment that involves making a program that interacts/modifies school grades (adding to, changing mark). Some functions change the grade from an int to a letter grade, another changes to the GPA version (1-4).

Here is a summary of the constraints listed on the assignment sheet:

- Use the specified overloaded operators
- Every overloaded operator in the code so far is required
- **Main.cpp file is provided; Do NOT modify it.**
- Return types according to what's instructed

My code works except for when the execution reaches the last two statements in main():

```
cout << (val += n) << endl;
cout << (val += k) << endl;
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
more than one conversion function from "sdds::Mark" to a built-in type applies:
function "sdds::Mark::operator int()" (declared at line 17 of "/Users/...)
function "sdds::Mark::operator double()" (declared at line 21 of "/Users/..)
function "sdds::Mark::operator char()" (declared at line 22 of "/Users/..)
more than one conversion function from "sdds::Mark" to a built-in type applies:
(same as above)
```

**How can I fix the ambiguity without modifying main?**
BTW, the comments are some instructions I copied from the assignment sheet, but not all of the instructions are in comments.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Mark.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;
int main()
{
   Mark n(25), k(200);
   int val = 60;
   cout << "int += Mark ..." << endl;
   cout << (val += n) << endl;
   cout << (val += k) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Mark.h**

```
namespace sdds {
class Mark
  {
    int markVal;
    void setEmpty();

  public:
    Mark();
    Mark(int val);
    bool markIsValid();
    operator int();

    Mark &operator+=(int addVal);
    Mark &operator=(int newMark);
    operator double();
    operator char();
  };
}
```

***CORRECT* Output of last two lines(not mine):**

```
int += Mark
140
140
```

Comment: Sure, but im not even sure where the bug is...i'll try. one sec.

Comment: Wow, that's a terrible design. I hope it is part of the "what not to do" curriculum. (To be clear, the guts of `main`, not your code that attempts to work with it.)

Comment: We need to actually see the code you wonder about. Without the definition of `Mark` we can only guess. My _guess_ is that `Mark::operator int` is `explicit` and that you need to follow the same pattern as earlier: `cout << static_cast<int>(val += n) << endl;`. Even after the update, it's not a [mre] and we still don't see the definition of `Mark`.

Comment: Unrelated: `int result; ...; return (int)result;` Why cast?

Comment: The contents of the function _definitions_ you are showing in `Mark.cpp` are completely irrelevant to resolving these errors. The errors are a result only of `main.cpp` and the definition of `Mark` in `Mark.h`. What you do in `Mark.cpp` can't affect it at all and we can't say anything without the contents of `Mark.h`.

Comment: However, absent something very unusual in the class definition of `Mark`, the problem is simply that your instructor has a wrong assumption on how overload resolution for built-in `+=` works according to the C++ standard, probably because some compilers do not implement it correctly and they relied on such a compiler to test the code. Your compiler is behaving correctly by rejecting the `+=` expressions if your class has (non-`explicit`) conversion functions to both `int` and `double`. Only way to resolve this is to make one of them `explicit`, but that would be a trick assignment then.

Comment: @user17732522 im not sure what you mean. is this not fixable without addressing main?

Comment: I vote to reopen. OP has now provided enough information to explain this (non-trivial) behavior.

Comment: @273K  is this better?

Comment: @chickpea The only way to resolve this is to write `explicit` before `operator double();` in `Mark.h`. `main.cpp` and `Mark.h` are not valid standard-C++ as written.

Comment: @user17732522 I wrote explicit operator double(); in Mark.h, but the error remains.

Comment: I jsut removed most of main; not sure why someone added it back in

Comment: @chickpea I added it back, because, in contrast to `Mark.cpp` it is important what exactly is written in it to answer the question. I am trying to get your question into a shape so that it is acceptable for the site and other users will also vote to reopen it...

Comment: @chickpea Ah, sorry, you need `explicit` before `operator char();` as well. Didn't notice that one.

Comment: Anyway, it is unlikely that your instructor is expecting you to figure out that you have to add these `explicit`. Realizing that they are necessary requires advanced understanding of how overload resolution in C++ works and I had to check in the standard itself to verify my own assumptions. It is not something that a beginner should need to figure out. If you aren't doing some pretty advanced course, I'd say it is more likely that your instructor didn't realize that there would be an issue themselves.

Comment: sorry guys, but i still havent fixed the issue

Comment: ook, i dont see the point in fixing the layout if no one is helping me answer. sorry. but this is due in a few hours and i cant be bothered with ppl's varying preferences for layout. edit it how u want

Comment: @chickpea Overloaded casting operators are frowned upon by many C++ programmers.  Even if you were to get this to compile, when your program runs, can you tell which functions are called, for example, whether it is the overloaded `int()`, or the "regular" int is used?  I bet your teacher will get it wrong.  I also bet that many here wouldn't get it right, unless they run it under a debugger to see the path the code is taking.  I wouldn't want to be put in a position where I can't look at code and know what function will actually be called.   That's why the C++ library itself rarely use them.

Comment: @chickpea -- That's why a class would have a `to_string()` or `to_double()`, etc. functions, and not `string()` or `double()` casting operators -- it is to prevent issues as you're seeing now.  The programmer, when they have to use `to_double`, `to_string`, etc., they are making the decision to do the conversion, and not a silent "conversion" operator, which they may not know is being used.

Comment: @RetiredNinja -- This is a horrible assignment given to the students.  IMO, the student wasted their time (and if they are paying for it, money) just to be frustrated in coming up with a program and design that in reality would be rejected in most, if not all, code reviews in the real world.  Conversion operators are rarely used, if not rejected altogether (even though they are part of C++).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie **This is a horrible assignment given to the students.** I don't think so. I would rather believe OP missed the instructor's lessons and the learning materials.

Comment: @273K Better to just teach them these operators exist, but use them very sparingly.

Comment: Admittedly we're looking at this from a piece of code and an incomplete description of the task. Teaching about conversion operators is a good thing as long as it's noted that they are generally used infrequently and it is almost always better to use a named function instead. It shows intent, makes code more readable, and is easier for a user of the class to understand. The concept of `explicit` is important on its own and I feel like there's probably a better way to teach it where it isn't  a gimmick to fix a very odd design problem. This just feels like a bad habit factory to me.

Answer (score 0):

As already it was said not a single time, declare all the conversional operators explicit:

```
explicit operator int();
explicit operator double();
explicit operator char();
```

And add the overloaded `operator+=` that takes `int` on the left hand:

```
Mark& operator+=(int addVal, const Mark &);
```

You will get the further error:

```
 error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'sdds::Mark')
```

You will need to overload the stream output operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Mark& m) {
  out << static_cast<T>(m);  // pick the type T
  return out;
}
```

Or convert the sum:

```
std::cout << static_cast<T>(val += k) << std::endl;  // pick the type T
```

What I got

```
#include <iostream>

namespace sdds {
class Mark
  {
    int markVal;
    void setEmpty();

  public:
    Mark();
    Mark(int val);
    bool markIsValid();

    Mark &operator+=(int addVal);
    Mark &operator=(int newMark);
    explicit operator int();
    explicit operator double();
    explicit operator char();
  };

  Mark& operator+=(int addVal, Mark &);

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Mark& m) {
    out << static_cast<int>(m);  // pick the type T
    return out;
  }
}

int main()
{
   sdds::Mark n(25);
   int val = 60;
   std::cout << "int += Mark ..." << std::endl;
   std::cout << (val += n) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're editing main. i can;t do that.

Comment: I didn't even realize the `@=` operators could be overloaded with free functions. That's pretty surprising. This means you probably actually want `int& operator+=(int& lhs, const Mark& rhs)`. It doesn't make much sense to me, but it would fit the constraints of the assignment.

Comment: I fixed it: I just had to add this at the end:

  int operator+=(const int val, Mark &obj)
  {
    int result = 0;
    if (val)
    { // Check if right is a valid mark
      result = obj.getMark() + val;
    }
    return result;
  };

Comment: If you are not allowed to change Main.cpp, use the first approach. I've updated the answer.